# How can compressed air jet from a characters hands?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, physics, body-modification

I was wondering if there is a way to have a person with added organs and systems to be able to shoot jets of compressed air out of their body without them needing a giant gas bag or massive lungs?

Having read other questions theres some great suggestions on how to biologically explain how a character can use electricity or fire as forms of attack which emanate from their body and I was wondering if the same can be done for air attacks.

I thought if they had many holes on their back that open up like large pores that suck air in to be compressed in an organ or part of the system then the compressed air could be jetted out through a hole in their palms so the streams of air could be controlled and used as an attack almost like water or plasma cutters.

Is this something that could work or are there any better ways to have the same effect that could seem almost realistic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the air to become compressed you'll need some sort of compressor mechanism in the body which will require space.

You'll also need space for the volume of air that you want to compress. The larger the volume, the more air you'll be able to move at a higher pressure but the longer it would take to reach that pressure.

Your storage lung would also need to be relatively stiffer for a fleshy organ in order to contain the pressure without changing size. Keeping it rubbery could also assist in exhaling the air.

To let the pressure out of your hands you'll also need the piping for that. You can add artificial nozzles to your hands to get the jet stream that you want, but they will probably make weird noises either way. Also when you are releasing pressure you might want to keep your hands stretched out.

You could use your lungs to fill the pressured pocket, requiring only that you can exhale to either your mouth or this pocket with a one way valve. This would limit the pressure in that pocket to the strength of your lungs being able to fill it. I don't think you can get to pressure levels you want without more serious changes to the body though.

Answer (score 1):

How fast do you want the air to be and how much do you need? Simple sneezing already ejects air from your nose at about 170 km/h (https://www.reference.com/science/average-speed-sneeze-c86f74d73acf454c).